# 太... 了 (tài... le) vs 很(hěn)

Tags: grammar

Are 太... 了 (tài... le) and 很(hěn) grammatically equivalent?

My feeling is that semantically 太... 了 (tài... le) is somehow "stronger" then 很(hěn), that is: 太... 了 (tài... le) seems "exceptionally, extremely", while 很(hěn) is just "very". Is it correct?

Summing up both questions with an example:

1. may I say (apart of changes in meaning):

   - 我的狗很大 Wǒ de ɡǒu hěn dà
   - 我的狗太大了 Wǒ de ɡǒu tài dà le

?

2. Is the meaning of the second sentence is somehow "stronger" ?

   - 我的狗很大 Wǒ de ɡǒu hěn dà -> my dog is very big)
   - 我的狗太大了 Wǒ de ɡǒu tài dà le -> my dog is so big! / my dog is too big!

Comment: If you have looked up 很 and 太 in dictionary, you wouldn't have to ask this question.

Comment: 太 is often recommended to use instead of 很 in the case of negative adjectives (or verbs)  很好，太坏；很高，太矮，verbs： 很喜欢，太麻烦

Answer (score 4):

很 sometime may interchange with 太 . however,  很 mostly carry out and descriptive meaning. While 太 are mean to show something exaggerate

if you use   太....  了, it will add extra expressive complaining tones.
For example :

```
# 很 versus 太
my dog is [very big](for the breed) 我的狗[个子*很*大] 
my dog is too big(for the house) 我的狗[个子*太*大]

# 太....  了
my dog is [just too big!] 我的狗[个子太大了!] or 我的狗[太大只了!]
```

The word  `大`,  carry a few meaning : `larger` OR `greater` OR `older`

When describe with living subject, you must put additional care , i.e. put an extra description.  Thus :

```
高大  : tall
肥大  : Fat and tall
强大  ：strong and powerful (more appropriate to use 强壮 for masculine） 
年纪大 ：old
```

我的狗很大, 我的狗太大了 is a confusing term.  Is it older? taller? Stronger?

```
我的狗很高大 -> my dog is tall
我的狗长大了 -> my dog grow up (,at last)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of interpreting 我的狗太大了 as "stronger" than 我的狗很大, the former one has more of a negative tone in it. If I exaggerate the first phrase a little bit more, it will be my dog is way too big. It has nuances of a complaint as compared to the mere description of 我的狗很大

Answer (score 1):

From my own point of view, 太...了 does convey a stronger feeling towards the thing you are describing than 很. You can consider 太 as meaning "very much" or "a lot", whereas 很 means "really".

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, 很(hěn) means "very" while 太... 了 (tài... le) means "over(ly)". So, the second is more stronger (over the limit).

Answer (score 1):

"太" is roughly translated as "too", while "很" is "very". In terms of the emotional senses, "太" has some stronger personal feelings in it, while "很" is normally objective and neutral